# Argument Valid Or Not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Premise 1 : $A \to B$

Premise 2 : $A \vee C$

Premise 3 : $C \to D$

Premise 4 : $\neg B$

Conclusion : $D$

How to check if the argument is valid?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Share your thoughts and we can help you understand. We will not answer your homework

Comment: using rule of inferences but i dont think I've able to solve it

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? are you unsure between D and B?

Comment: i already found the answer! thanks man!

Comment: Great, and you learned something :)

Comment: Appreciate that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Premise 1 is equivalent to
$$
\lnot B\to \lnot A
$$
Now, use it with premise 4 and then with premises 2 and 3 respectively to conclude what you want.

Comment: alright,  thanks! i will try to figure it out

Comment: Thanks man!  i already figure it out!

Comment: All the bests (thumbs up!)